# Can I create symbolic links in OS X which also work in Windows/Linux and vice versa?

Tags: windows, unix, symlink

I'm synchronizing a folder structure between my MacBook (OS X 10.6) and a PC with Windows XP (soon Linux or Windows 7).

My problem is that Windows shortcuts or OS X aliases seem to be unusable on the other system, so those symbolic links can not be synchronized with the other machine.

- Is there a common format for symbolic links which works on all 3 operating systems (Windows, OS X, Linux)?
- Can I convert the existing aliases and Windows shortcuts to this format?

Comment: symbolic links are the same in OS X and Linux - aliases are not symbolic links

Comment: `what about MS WIndows?` and can I "convert" aliases into symlinks?

Comment: No an OS X axis has more info than a symlink - it will change if you move the thing it points to via the finder, a symlink just contains a text path name to where you first create the link (not the symlink contains a Unix path whilst a NTFS shortcut is a Windows path possibly including a drive letter - how can you map that to a Unix path) Some symlinks can map to Windows shortcuts but definitely not all Also not HFS+ has hard directory links that do not map to other filesystems

Answer (score -1):

sync application may be the good choice sometime, I recommend you
[BitTorrent Sync](http://www.getsync.com), is An Application to keep designated folder content same on  more devices. Changes should be propagated to all the device that keep the folder synchronized.

Comment: does BitTorrent Sync also sync symbolic links, so that they are usable on the different operating systems (in Finder/Windows Explorer)? *That* is my real question, I'm currently using `Unison File Synchronizer` for sync'ing

Comment: I don't think it can